# sshtunnel forwarding and mysql connection on google cloud function

Tags: python, mysql, ssh, google-cloud-functions, mysql-python

I am trying to connect to a MySQL server through ssh tunnel on one of my google cloud functions. This works fine in my home environment. I assume it is some port issue on cloud function.

Edit: For clarification the MySQL server sits on a Namecheap shared hosting web server. Not Google Cloud SQL

Every time I run this I timeout with "unknown error". The tunnel appears to be successful. I am however unable to get the mysql connection to work.

```
import base64
import sshtunnel
import mysql.connector

def testing(event, context):
    """
    Testing function
    """
    with sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder(
        ("server address", port),
        ssh_username="user",
        ssh_password="password",
        remote_bind_address=("127.0.0.1",3306),
    ) as server:
        print(server.local_bind_port)
        with mysql.connector.connect(
            user="user",
            password="password",
            host="localhost",
            database="database",
            port=server.local_bind_port
        ) as connection:
            print(connection)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's too many steps to list, but I'm wondering if the "connector" setup plays a difference even for SSH. Maybe you have to create a connector as shown [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-functions#configuring) (notice how the instructions in "Private IP" tab are different than on your local computer). Then, configure Cloud Functions to use that connector. Make sure you also use the right port.

> A Serverless VPC Access connector handles communication to your VPC
> network. To connect directly with private IP, you need to:
>
> 1. Make sure that the Cloud SQL instance created above has a private IP
>    address. If you need to add one, see the Configuring private IP page
>    for instructions.
> 2. Create a Serverless VPC Access connector in the same
>    VPC network as your Cloud SQL instance. Unless you're using Shared
>    VPC, a connector must be in the same project and region as the
>    resource that uses it, but the connector can send traffic to resources
>    in different regions. Serverless VPC Access supports communication to VPC networks connected via Cloud VPN and VPC Network Peering. Serverless VPC Access does not support legacy networks.
> 3. Configure Cloud Functions to use the connector.
> 4. Connect using your
>    instance's private IP and port 3306.

Keep in mind, this "unknown" error could also very well be due to the Cloud SQL Admin API not being enabled [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-functions#setting_up_a_instance). As a matter of fact, make sure you follow that entire page as it's a broad question.

Let us know what worked for this type of error.

Comment: The MySQL server I am trying to access is hosted on a Namecheap shared hosting web server not Cloud SQL

Comment: If the direction is CF to SQL and the tunnel appears to be successful, I would think it goes past Google. But because CF is serverless (http/no IP given), and if Namecheap requires whitelisting, then you will need to associate it with a static IP like [so](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings#associate-static-ip). Otherwise, if no IP is required and whether inbound/outbound, then look for ("all traffic") settings on that article to make sure everything is open. None of these configurations have been specified in your post and by default CF is private, without IP.